# How to import, module present in one folder, in another module present in another folder

Tags: python-2.7, module, python-import

If i have a 'a.py' file in folder A, and one more file, 'b.py' in folder B, then how to import 'a.py' in 'b.py' in python?

Comment: Give the full structure of your project. How A is located in respect of B ? a sub-directory ?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Give the directory structure of your project

Comment: Both folders are parallel to each other, in one drive, lets say in E drive.

The folder structure is like this:

E:\a\a.py
E:\b\b.py